# Why doesn't the cart contain any items when called from REST?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

According to the [rest api](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/quoteCartManagementV1/quoteCartManagementV1GetCartForCustomerGet), calling `/V1/carts/mine` should return json with

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "created_at": "2016-04-05 12:02:58",
  ...
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": 0,
      "sku": "string",
   ...
```

That is, `items` should be an array with products. But when I call this endpoint, that attribute is missing. Instead, I get this back:

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "created_at": "2016-04-05 12:02:58",  
  "items_count": 1,
  "items_qty": 58,
  "customer": {
  ...
```

So, instead of the array, it just gives me `items_qty` and `items_count`. Is the docs incorrect, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did my answer solve you problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. the Magento API still needs a lot of love to be really useful for us frontend devs..

Try making a request to this url instead.

```
/V1/carts/mine/items
```

It will give you the items in the cart. But here we are missing cart total sum, items thumbnails etc etc...